# How can I display an image in the terminal?

Tags: image, terminal, image-conversion, ascii-art

Is there any sort of utility I can use to convert an image to ASCII and then print it in my terminal? I looked for one but couldn't seem to find any.

Comment: Note that there are some terminals that let you display an image without converting it to text. They just display an image. For example, the kitty terminal can do this.

Answer (score 10):

A program called [cacaview](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cacaview) allows you to do this.

It is interactive, allowing you to pan, zoom, and change display modes.

[image: Cacaview example]

([Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwrLb.png))

Comment: `cacaview` opens a new window, it doesn't print out the image to the terminal, at least not in Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a command line option, but you can just execute clearing the DISPLAY environment variable to have it run in the current terminal: `DISPLAY= cacaview yourimage.jpg`

Comment: Setting `DISPLAY=` does work, but it takes over the terminal screen, it doesn't print out to the terminal like `echo` would.

Comment: See meduz's answer below - `img2txt` uses the same underlying code as `cacaview`, but prints to console like you're looking for 

Answer (score 8):

## Chafa

I like to use `chafa`.

```
chafa example.png
```

[image: Screenshot]

You can download Chafa from [Chafa's website](https://hpjansson.org/chafa/download/) or from your favourite package manager, like APT:

```
sudo apt install chafa
```

Answer (score 6):

more simply, you may use `img2txt` from the caca library (`cacaview` is an image browser and opens a new window, which is not what is asked here I guess);

For instance :

[image: Screenshot]

on macosx, you may use homebrew :

```
$ brew reinstall libcaca --with-imlib2
```

(imlib is used to convert from different formats)

Comment: The default Homebrew install for libcaca (that is, without passing `--with-imlib2`) doesn't seem to be able to open any files.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the Google-Ninja before asking!
I found [cacaview](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cacaview) and [aview](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aview/).

Comment: and now this page became the first google's answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

A high quality fast standalone conversion utility (provided you have a 256 color terminal) is `pxl`, available at https://github.com/ichinaski/pxl.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a utility that does this (with source code):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10949/ASCII-Art-Generator

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the Ipython notebook: it is pretty good at doing what you ask for.

For bash: You have to prepend commands with a bang.
For images: You may use the [rich display system](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb) from ipython.

A screenshot of the result:

[image: screenshot of the result]

Complete answer in this [post](http://blog.invibe.net/posts/14-10-16-how-can-i-display-an-image-in-the-terminal.html).